# Limit memory usage of an application with multiple instances

Tags: memory, sql-server

I got a program installed in 3 different machines, pointing to the same database, running at the same time. They are responsible for reading a huge file, process everything and then save on database.
The database is running on the main machine and we can have multiple instances of the same program running.

When there are multiple instances running on the main machine (physical machine running Windows Server 2016) the memory percentage increases to 96 and the database timeouts.

**I see 3 potential approaches:**

**1 -** Limit the amount of memory available in SQL Server to X% of the free memory on the server. With this approach SQL server memory would scale down as more apps start up.

**2 -** Limit the amount of memory available to apps in Windows Server. This would allow me to never hog all server resources when sql server and many app instances are competing for memory. Windows Server would allow up to Y% of memory to be used by all user apps (SQL Server included).

**3 -** Limit the amount memory usage of all instances to like 60% of the max memory.

Is there a way I can implement any of these scenarios? If all of them are possible, which one scales better in windows? Can you point me on the right direction to implement such limitations?

Comment: Supposing we're talking about physical machines and not virtual ones, and without knowing what kind of hardware they're running on (multicore CPU's?), you can either set CPU core affinity for each instance, or use a third-party such as Process Hacker to reduce current working set on each instance. You can also try the programmatical approach (see here, regarding Win7, but it applies to Win Server too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841845/clear-the-windows-7-standby-memory-programmatically), but it's going to require a little finesse, what with juggling with several platforms.

Comment: ` Limit the amount of memory available in SQL Server`. You should already be doing this.